# for select group issue

Tags: go, select, concurrency, channel

I am trying to write a function to execute multiple jobs, when all the jobs are done, I want the control to go after wg.Wait(). I have mentioned different problems, I am facing in comments in the code.

How can I make it work?

```
func (q *ChanExecutor) Perform(ctx context.Context, name string, taskData *interface{}) chan *job.JobResult {
    var waitgroup sync.WaitGroup
    waitgroup.Add(1)
    go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        for j := range q.jobCh { // This is the channel which gives jobs
            wg.Add(1)
            go func(qq *ChanExecutor, jVal job.Job) { // we are just passing these values to closure. Is this necessary?
                jobResultChannel:= jVal.Do(ctx) // Here we are executing the job as result which sends another channel of results
                donech := jVal.DoneCh() // Job returns another channel which tells if that job is done
                for true {
                    select {
                    case res := <-jobResultChannel:
                        q.result <- res // From the result we are passing that result to another channel
                    case syncJobDone := <-donech:
                        if syncJobDone {
                            donech = nil // here if the donech receives true it should come out of the select and for loop and the goroutine. How to do that?
                            // Another thing here, if the donech returns true before jobResultChannel then it should still go to jobResultChannel's case block
                            // The jVal.Do(ctx) executes the job and returns channel but in my case before starting the forloop both channels has values and donech has true value
                            wg.Done()
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }
            }(q, *j)
        }
    }(&waitgroup)
    go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup, qq *ChanExecutor) {
        time.Sleep(200 * time.Millisecond) // Here is another blunder. If I don't sleep here, randomly, it goes after wg.Wait()
        // even though all the jobs are not done.
        wg.Done() // REmoving the one which was added immediately after creating wg instance.
        wg.Wait()
        fmt.Println("Wait finish")
        qq.Done()
    }(&waitgroup, q)
    fmt.Printf("returning result channel not result")
    return q.result
}
```

Comment: You declare a nested function, and call it immediately. Why is that so? Since you called it, it will run until all the messages are processed, and only after that the second goroutine will start running. Is this really what you intended?

Comment: Sorry that function was the goroutine. In copy pasting and editiong it got lost. I edited the code now

Answer (score 0):

First, you should remove the sleep and `wg.Done` from the second goroutine. It is sometimes failing without the sleep because sometimes the first goroutine does not have a chance to add to the `wg` before the second one removes it.

Second, you're trying to terminate the goroutine, so do just that:

```
if syncJobDone {
   wg.Done()
   return
}
```